# Use symbolic constant in actor receive block cases to match conditions

Tags: scala, akka

I want to use symbolic constant in actor receive block cases to match conditions.

```
    val str1 = "This is just a demo string to match"
    val date = OffsetDateTime.parse("some date")
        def receive: Receive = {
          case CaseClassA(**str1**, **date**) =>
            sender() ! Some("data")
```

I want to do something like that :

```
case CaseClassA(**str1**, **date**)
```

But it does not consider the constants. I have to write it in the  manner:

```
case CaseClassA("This is just a demo string to match", OffsetDateTime.parse("some date"))
```

Is there any way i can use symbolic constants?

Answer (score 4):

Try surrounding `str1` and `data` in backquotes (backticks) like so

```
case CaseClassA(`str1`, `date`) =>
```

According to [SLS - 8.1.6 Stable Identifier Patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns):

> To resolve the syntactic overlap with a variable pattern, a stable
>   identifier pattern may not be a simple name starting with a lower-case
>   letter. However, it is possible to enclose such a variable name in
>   backquotes; then it is treated as a stable identifier pattern